# setState after useEffect() finish and has value

Tags: reactjs

```
const initData = {
    name: "",
    class: ""
}
const [currentStudent, setCurrentStudent] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    // My example code to setState
    setCurrentStudent(exampleData)
    //The result of currentStudent is {name: "Alex", class: "4"}
}, []);
     
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ condition ? currentStudent : initData });
```

It's mean if true `formData` has result is `currentStudent` `{name: "Alex", class: "4"}`, if false will `initData` state.

But result when I tried the code above is an emty object like this `{}`.

How can I set `formData` state =  `currentStudent` `({name: "Alex", class: "4"})`

Comment: useEffect is not synchronous. So even though its called after useEffect, the internal function handed to useEffect hasn't run yet.

Comment: You have to set the desired state inside the useEffect hook, I mean declare it first and then update/set inside useEffect

Answer (score 1):

i am change code .

```
const initData = {
  name: "",
  class: ""
}
const [currentStudent, setCurrentStudent] = useState({});
const [formData, setFormData] =useState({});
useEffect(() => {
  setCurrentStudent(exampleData)   // My example code to setState
                                  //The result of currentStudent is {name: "Alex", class: "4"}
  setFormData(condition ? exampleData: initData);
}, []);
```

Comment: I tried this before but it not done. the result of `formData` is an empty Object `{}` when i `console.log()` on `useEffect`

Comment: yes .ok . in ```return``` write ```{formData}```.and what's see result?

Comment: @Alex  .Applying `useEffect` may also be queuing. This means that if we try to read the updated state after calling `setFormData`, we may get the wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one.

```
const initData = {
  name: "",
  class: ""
}
const [currentStudent, setCurrentStudent] = useState({});
const [formData, setFormData] =useState({});
useEffect(() => {
  setCurrentStudent(exampleData)
  setFormData(condition ? exampleData: initData);
}, [condition]); // or use props variable which is used for condition value.
```

It's aiming to update the functional component when the props change.
As the condition is mostly set from the props, it is needed to set props or condition as parameters in `userEffect` like `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Answer (score 0):

First time component render, init value state will be applied. You have set current user after that. It will not be applied. why dont you set in init of setState:

```
const [currentStudent, setCurrentStudent] = useState(exampleData);
```

Or you can set it `useEffect` function:

```
setFormData(condition ? exampleData : initData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState( condition ? currentStudent : initData);
```